# Is there any text editor that will show code highlighting for Visual Basic code?

Tags: editors, ide, plugin

I have some Visual Basic Application (VBA) code that I need to tweak. Note: I don't need any help in the coding aspect of it; this is not a programming question.

When I opened the .vba file in Kate or Gedit, I saw that neither of them have highlighting/syntax knowledge of Visual Basic code. I understand that I cannot actually run vba code natively, but I would like to know if there exists a plugin that will run on some text editor to do basic code highlighting.

Does anyone know of a text editor or custom written plugin that I can use?

Comment: `gedit` supports VB.NET syntax out of the box. It's in `view -> highlight mode -> sources`

Comment: Ah! You're right. I missed that when I first looked, and I know Kate doesn't have it. If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @StephenSchrauger: `gedit` to write code is a very, very lousy piece of advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gedit` supports VB.NET syntax out of the box. It's in `view -> highlight mode -> sources`

Comment: Writing code in `gedit` is - well, not recommended to say the least.

Comment: Why not?  I use Emacs myself for everything, but I can understand why some people would prefer a more lightweight tool.  Gedit does syntax highlighting, paren matching, and automatic backups, which I'd consider the top three most important features for a code editor.  I would save your disapproval for programmers who use Nano, or Windows Notepad.

Answer (score 2):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) supports Visual Basic syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `vim` with visual basic highlighting as Evan indicated, there is also a [visual basic mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/visual-basic-mode.el) for Emacs. I have not  used it extensively as I seldom work with VBA.

You would have to follow the installations instruction in the file the link points to.

Emacs is not a lightweight editor like Gedit is, it is well worth learning to use something as powerful as Emacs.

Comment: Read this to understand why you should learn how to use a powerful editor such as Vim or Emacs: http://www.rudism.com/s/vimcreep. The article is about Vim but its points apply to Emacs as well.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I started with `vi` (actually `ed`) and learned Emacs much later, when I had a Sparcstation-1. For a long time I liked emacs (and its extensions) better. I never completely dropped using `vi` though, and with `vim` the usage has become about 50-50. Both are well worth learning.